# How to set a recursive steps counter using MySQL data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursion

So, I'm creating a mini strategy game for fun, and stumbled upon an issue I can't really sort out.

I thought it would be easy, but seems I was wrong, or maybe the solution is right under my nose, but I'm looking for another view on my problem.

I have a database with a list of Territories recorded on a Map. Each of these territories hold a list of adjacent territories.

> ```
> ID | name  | adjacent     | faction
>
> 1  | Name1 | 2;7;10;24    | 5
> 2  | Name2 | 1;3;7;8      | 4
> 3  | Name3 | 2;4;5;8      | 8
> ```

adjacent being a list of IDs separated by semi-colon

My goal is to find the shortest route to a territory from all territories held by a certain faction. The distance is calculated by the amount of steps required to reach the territory.

This way, I can quickly get the distance and apply modifiers in this regard.

For instance, in the data snippet above:

- Territory 1 is at 0 distance from 2, since they're adjacent.
- Territory 1 is at 1 distance from 3, since 3 is adjacent to 2 (and 2 is adjacent to 1).
- Territory 1 is at 2 distance from 4, since 4 is adjacent to 3, which is adjacent to 2.

Currently, my code looks like this;

```
function getProximity($connexion, $faction, $terrain)
{
    $query = "SELECT id, adjacent FROM worldmap WHERE faction = ".$faction;
    $result = mysqli_query($connexion, $query);

    $proximity = 10;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $adjacent = explode(";", $row[1]);
        if (in_array($terrain, $adjacent))
        {
            //territory is adjacent, stop looking
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //if not directly adjacent, seek through the list
            foreach($adjacent as $adj)
            {
                $prox = getSubProximity($connexion, array($row[0]), $adj, $terrain, 1);
                if ($prox < $proximity)
                {
                    $proximity = $prox;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $proximity;
}

function getSubProximity($connexion, $from, $terrain, $terrain2, $proximity)
{
    //Attempt to break weird loops... not succesful...
    if ($proximity > 10)
    {
        return $proximity;
    }
    $query = "SELECT id, adjacent FROM worldmap WHERE id = ".$terrain;
    $result = mysqli_query($connexion, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $adjacent = explode(";", $row[1]);
        if (in_array($terrain2, $adjacent))
        {
            //territory is adjacent, stop looping
            return $proximity;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($adjacent as $adj)
            {
                //check if we've been through there
                if (!in_array($adj, $from))
                {
                    array_push($from, $terrain);
                    $prox = getSubProximity($connexion, $from, $adj, $terrain2, $proximity+1);
                    if ($prox < $proximity)
                    {
                        $proximity = $prox;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help, and feel free if you have other ways to get the same result; the database structure isn't static and fully under my control.

Comment: adjacent should probably be another table with a [one-to-many relationship](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561).

Comment: Not a bad point for using another table, but I'd probably still be stuck in the same place unless you're thinking of a solution in SQL

Comment: it would make it much easier to SQL query related neighbours   but really where in your SQL data is any distance value held? I see no data about distance so I have no clue (and SQL has no clue) how to work out shortest route from *a* to *b*

Comment: The distance is calculated by the amount of step required to reach the territory.

Comment: I added SQL tags to help so those with more SQL knowledge than me can see this `:-)`

Comment: How many records do you have approximately in your table?

Comment: (1) MySQL has almost no support for recursive queries; (2) Storing *numeric* ids in a single *string* field is definitely not the SQLish way to store things.

Comment: @trincot as for now I have about 50 territories, not much more, and I don't plan to extend it much further either. At best it could go up to a hundred.

Comment: If interested in an SQLish solution, see normalisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things I would suggest:

- MySql is not so strong in working with self-referencing/hierarchical data, so against the usual answer ("do it in SQL"), perform the logic in PHP.
- Since the total data set is relatively small, read all the territories' data in memory with one query, and then leave the database out of it.
- Perform a non-recursive, breadth first search. This way you only need to visit any world territory at most once.
- Keep a list of territories that you have already visited, to avoid endless looping in circles, and use an associative array for this so you get fast key lookup (instead of inefficient `in_array`). It is not enough to just keep note of a `$from` territory.

Here is the outline of such code:

```
// This function returns the whole data set in a nice data structure 
function getProximityData($connexion) {
    $query = "SELECT id, adjacent, faction FROM worldmap";
    $result = mysqli_query($connexion, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $territories[$row[0]] = [
            "adjacent" => explode(";", $row[1]),
            "faction" => $row[2]
        ];
    }
    return $territories;
}

function getProximity($territories, $faction, $terrain) {
    // mark this terrain as visited
    $visited[$terrain] = 1;
    // Create queue for breadth first search
    $queue = [$terrain];
    $steps = 0;
    while (count($queue)) {
        $next = [];
        foreach($queue as $terrain) {
            if ($territories[$terrain]["faction"] === $faction) {
                // Territory belongs to the faction, stop looking
                return $steps;
            }
            // collect list of unvisited neighbours of this terrain
            foreach($territories[$terrain]["adjacent"] as $adj) {
                if (!isset($visited[$adj])) { // not yet visited
                    $next[] = $adj;
                    $visited[$adj] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        $queue = $next;
        $steps++;
    }
    // Should never get here: it would mean territories are disconnected
}

// Load the world map: 
$territories = getProximityData($connexion);

// Example use:
$steps = getProximity($territories, 5, 4); // distance of faction 5 to territory 4.
```

Note that 0 will be returned for a territory (last argument) that is owned by the given faction (second argument). For a territory that is adjacent to the faction you'll get 1, ...etc.

Comment: I'll definitely need some time to study this code deeply, but you sir are a hero.

This works 100%. As for myself, I promise I won't just copy/paste mindlessly and take the time to understand all of this :)